# SLDS SVG Icons not showing in IE 11

Tags: visualforce, lightning, slds

SLDS SVG icons not displaying on IE 11, having this issue with IE only, it works for rest of the browsers.

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: So many issues with IE. is IE just bad or is everyone else doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To use SVG spritemap image icons with Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 you will need to download a small script called [SVG for Everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody). After you download svg4everybody, add the svg4everybody.min.js script as a static resource, include it in your pages, and call it in a  tag.

Please refer to the full instructions on the svg4everybody website for more details.

```
<head>
      <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.REPLACE_WITH_NAME_OF_SVG4EVERYBODY_STATIC_RESOURCE}" />
  <script>
    svg4everybody();
  </script>

</head>
```